How do I link a stylesheet in Liquid?
I am trying to build a custom Jekyll theme, and I need to link a stylesheet to my liquid file. I've tried doing this the "HTML Way", where you link a stylesheet like this, <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">, but it doesn't work.
For some more context (this may be important), my folder structure looks something like this,
_layouts
  default.liquid
stylesheets
  styles.css

How do I make link styles.css to default.liquid? Any and all help is appreciated, thank you!

The following should work:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{site.baseurl}}/stylesheets/styles.css">


Thanks, this worked for me! I cant upvote due to not having enough reputation but the answer is appreciated
