Jekyll is unable to detect my Stylesheets
I have created a Jekyll site, and ran jekyll serve --livereload. However, every time I refresh, there will be a warning message saying, [2024-10-22 18:06:45] ERROR /assets/stylesheets/styles.css' not found., which dosn't make sense since I linked the stylesheet.
Site Structure:
_layouts/
  default.html
assets/
  stylesheets/
    styles.css

Inside defaut.html, I linked the stylesheet as so:
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/stylesheets/styles.css">

but it just keeps on saying the stylesheet isn't detected.

Is this the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79106621/how-do-i-link-a-stylesheet-in-liquid/79106689 except that you have added the assets folder?

@mb21 it's not the same question, I'm using HTML Instead of Liquid, but the traditional HTML method of linking a stylesheet isn't working

default.html will still run through the liquid templating engine, see https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/04-layouts/#creating-a-layout Otherwise the {{content}} thing wouldn't be replaced either.

Oh ok, so I have to use the answer you have for the liquid question all the time.
